# Why does commiting and pushing my code to Github break my Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, deployment

I have a project with a frontend and a backend folder. Initially, I have already deployed it by building the frontend, copy pasting its contents to the public folder of my backend then running these commands: heroku create mytrialapp1427 ; git add . ; git commit -m "msg" ; git push heroku master.
After this sequence, my app has been deployed and it works!

Afterwards, I went back to VS Code->Source Control then committed and push my code. The checkout branch is 2nd-branch.

Now when I try to redeploy my app again because I made changes I did these sequence of commands: git init ; git add . ; git commit -m "redeploy" ; git push heroku master ; The terminal did not show any errors but when I go to my app, the console says

/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico:1

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json:1

```
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Going to heroku logs just shows this:
2023-12-15T14:13:13.795111+00:00 app[web.1]: /%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico GET

```
2023-12-15T14:13:13.795714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" host=persafs-sp-3c63f714108a.herokuapp.com request_id=e84e6059-e52b-44e3-a9ab-058ed66d6311 fwd="112.206.71.232" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=411 protocol=https
```

If I try redeploying using the steps earlier, it says "On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean" and then "Everything up-to-date" when I try git push heroku master.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

I have tried heroku git:remote -a mytrialapp1427 and then git push heroku master.

I have also tried git:remote -a mytrialapp1427 ; git add . ; git commit -m "msg" ; git push heroku master.

I think the problem has to do with that there are two branches on my project folder: master and 2nd-branch while my backend folder inside project folder has a branch called master.

Answer (score 0):

After building my frontend and copying the contents to the public folder of backend, I deleted favicon and it works now and I don't know why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).